# Design Patterns in ASP .NET MVC Application

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Can somebody give me a link to article or name of book, where i can find something about Design Patterns in ASP .NET MVC applications? Sry if i asking for something stupid, i'm not expert in this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd recommend [Steven Sanderson's book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430228865) for how to use MVC (probably worth waiting for the MVC 3 version which is due soon)

Otherwise I'd look at general design patterns books like [Head First Design Patterns](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596007126) as these still apply within MVC.

Do you have a more specific question around a particular design pattern?

Comment: It would be perfect, if i can find information about applying a lot of design patterns in MVC application, with their "+" and "-", when which i have to use and examples in TDD. Something like Nerddiner in 10 relization :) I hope when i read Head First Design Patterns, i won't need this. Thx alot. p.s. I've already bought alpha-version of MVC 3 ;)

Answer (score 3):

MVC itself is a design pattern. You can use several combinations of other design patterns in your application to suit your particular needs.

If you want a read an excellent book on ASP.NET MVC then I would recommend Steven Sanderson's book - http://www.amazon.co.uk/Pro-ASP-NET-Framework-Steven-Sanderson/dp/1430210079

Note: This book is available for MVC2 as well, but I have not read that one. This book uses several good concepts that will help you create a production ASP.NET MVC application including TDD, repository pattern etc

Comment: Yeah, thx. I've already read this, mb without needed attention.

Answer (score 2):

The official Microsoft website is actually very good for this. http://www.asp.net/mvc. I actually used Rob Conery's MVC store front video to get started (http://www.asp.net/mvc/videos/aspnet-mvc-storefront-part-1-architectural-discussion-and-overview). He goes through the repository pattern and a few other good practices for MVC, it's a little outdated now in some areas as it is written in MVC 1 but a lot of the points still hold.

Comment: I've already seen and read all what was there. Need something more, more and more :) Thx.

Answer (score 0):

Dino Esposito and Andrea Saltarello have a very good explanation and demystification of the MVC pattern on their book "[Microsoft .NET: Architecting Applications for the Enterprise](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/073562609X)". I've got a review of the MVC chapter of their book [in my blog](http://hectorcorrea.com/Blog/The-Model-View-Controller-is-dead-long-live-the-Model-View-Controller)